# Is there a way to change Struts 2 extension through web.xml without using struts configuration?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts, web.xml

There is a constant that can be defined in `struts.xml`

```
  <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="htm"/>
```

but I want to minimize the usage of configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>struts.action.extension</param-name>
        <param-value>htm</param-value>
    </init-param>       
</filter>
```